# clearInterval doesn't work if is in click jquery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval, jquery-events

I want to use `clearInterval` but I don't know why doesn't work.

```
var orologio_real;  //global variable 

$(document).ready(function(){
    orologio(1);

    $('#change-time').on('click', function(){
        clearInterval(orologio_real);   
        orologio(0);
    });
});

function orologio (arg){
    orologio_real= setInterval(function(){
    alert(arg)
    }, 1000);
}
```

What I don't understand is why if I click on div, `clearInterval` doesn't work

Comment: Is the click event bound???

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry @A.Wolff

Comment: You are setting the timer inside click as well, after you cleared it. You should move the orologio function call outside of click handler

Comment: @Borja Is the click handler called when you click your element? Check by setting a console log inside it. Is it shown?

Comment: @A.Wolff yes...anyway is only click event in page (and on that element)

Comment: @Borja Your code works as expected so i'm not sure what you are expecting. Provide a minimalistic sample replicating your issue and explain more clearly what you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a silly mistake. You are setting the time interval all over again inside the click handler. I commented it out, and increased the interval a little so that you get time to click the button

```
var orologio_real;  //global variable 

$(document).ready(function(){
    orologio(1);

    $('#change-time').on('click', function(){
        clearInterval(orologio_real);   
        //orologio(0); //this was the issue
    });
});

function orologio (arg){
    orologio_real= setInterval(function(){
    console.log(arg);
    alert(arg);
    }, 3000);
}
```